# How to make easy_install see libraries installed by homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew, easy-install, pygraphviz

My use case: I installed graphviz using homebrew. It's installed with include headers and dynamic libraries into `/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz`, which is great. Then I tried installing pygraphviz with easy_install, but got the following error:

```
pygraphviz/graphviz_wrap.c:2954:10: fatal error: 'graphviz/cgraph.h'
file not found
#include "graphviz/cgraph.h"
```

I can add the include path manually, but then the linker complains about not finding the dynamic libraries. Again, I can specify the paths manually, but it seems that it should Just Work (TM). So, why doesn't easy_install play nice with homebrew-installed libraries?

Comment: do you get a similar error, when you use `pip` instead of the old-fashioned `easy_install`?

Comment: @cel, yes, I get the same error.